# Почему после компиляции приложения в exe файл с помощью pyinstaller windows defender не дает запустить мое приложение и говорит, что это вирус

Tags: python, pyinstaller

В общем я сделал приложение для вычисления ИМТ на python, скомпилировал этот файл в exe с помощью pyinstaller, и в первый раз у меня все запустилось. Но когда я перезагрузил компьютер windows defender выдал ошибку сказав, что в этом приложении вирус. В итоге я разрешил компьютеру запускать его, так как знаю, что вирусов в моем приложении нет, но все равно как избавиться от этой ошибки при следующих компиляциях?

Comment: Никак. То, что создает любой "компилятор" питона - самораспаковывающийся архив, а это по умолчанию распознается как вирус.

Comment: То есть все таки вируса там нет?

Comment: Потому что кто-то когда-то запаковал таким образом вирус. На него пожаловались. Специалисты внесли сигнатуру в базу вирусных сигнатур. А сигнатура, так оказалось, смотрела не на код вируса, а на код общий для всех exe из pyinstaller. Конец истории.

Comment: С другой стороны, вы можете быть уверены что в вашем коде нет вирусов. Но как вы узнали что ваша копия pyinstaller не заражена?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что при компиляции .py скрипта, pyinstaller создаёт самораспаковывающийся архив, включающий *облегчённую* версию вашего Python(без неиспользуемых в скрипте модулей) и ваш скрипт. Некоторые вирусы себя *скрывают*, запаковываясь в самораспаковывающийся архив, поэтому и получается, что Windows Defender считает твою самораспаковывающуюся программу вирусом.

Самое лёгкое решение - удалить флаг "--onefile", чтобы pyinstaller не запаковывал твою получившуюся директорию с программой в самораспаковывающийся архив.

Другое возможное решение - воспользоваться альтернативой Pyinstaller - Nuitka. Опции сборки почти одинаковые, а размер получившегося файла будет меньше чем через Pyinstaller.

Comment: Но получается, что вируса нет?

Comment: @Али-МухаммадЗакарьяев да, поэтому волноваться не стоит :)

Comment: Спасибо большое!